# How to create a dynamic list on cloudformation based on the number of items in a parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, amazon-rds

I want to create a DB Proxy using cloudformation, this is a portion of the template:

```
Parameters:
    SecretManagerArn:
        Type: CommaDelimitedList
        Description: ARN of the AWS Secrets Manager secret containing DB connection parameters
Resources:
        RDSProxy:
            Type: AWS::RDS::DBProxy
            Properties:
              Auth:
                - AuthScheme: SECRETS
                  IAMAuth: REQUIRED
                  SecretArn: !Ref SecretManagerArn1
                - AuthScheme: SECRETS
                  IAMAuth: REQUIRED
                  SecretArn: !Ref SecretManagerArn2
              DBProxyName: "supersecretname"
              EngineFamily: POSTGRESQL
              RequireTLS: true
              RoleArn: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
              VpcSubnetIds: !Ref VpcSubnetIds
              VpcSecurityGroupIds: !Ref VpcSGIds
```

For now I can handle the number of secrets adding Auth blocks into the DBProxy resource "manually", but I want to create dynamic blocks depending on the number of secrets Arns that I pass in the comma delimited list, is  that possible?

Comment: No, its not possible.

Comment: Any suggested workaround?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to create dynamic blocks in CloudFormation is if you are going to develop a custom [macro](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-macros.html) for that. The macro, in a form of a lambda function, would process and modify the your template to add those dynamic blocks.

Comment: This is the answer, but another question you should ask yourself is maybe if cloudformation is the best tool here. There are others that can do things like this without as much work. Maybe look at CDK.